# Learning Tags - Should they be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have tags [lg.learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg.learning), [machine-learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), and [online-learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-learning). Is there a difference? If so, somebody should edit the tag wikis to make it clear.

Comment: Certainly, the wiki of [tag:lg.learning] suggests that it encompasses [tag:machine-learning].

Comment: I noticed that. There are indeed a lot of questions with both tags. I see now there was a [previous meta question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/343/machine-learning-vs-learning-theory-vs-both) discussing this, so maybe we don't have to do anything.

Comment: As a side note, my personal opinion is that it is better to leave decisions about tag merges/synonyms to the researchers in the related area since they are the people who really use those tags (unless the tags start to cause problems, e.g. repeated mistagging).

Answer (score 1):

I think the consensus from that meta question was that lg.learning refers to learning-theory (defined as COLT/ALT type work) and machine learning is the broader category.

Comment: So machine learning is actually the top-level tag in this case?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure that things should be this way.  I think of the machine-learning tag as the theory of machine learning, which is different from lg.learning. The former tag, for example, isn't concerned with learning monotone DNF, while the latter tag is.  I view machine-learning tag as ICML theory track and the lg.learning tag as COLT/ALT.

Comment: so lg.learning would not contain (for example) algorithms for variational inference, or graphical model work, or MCMC ?

Comment: right - at least in my worldview.  of course, we need to all agree on the proper uses for these tags...

Comment: I don't think the arxiv agrees with you though: look at this list: http://arxiv.org/list/cs.LG/11

Comment: You're right, but I wasn't so happy when lg.learning and learning-theory became synonyms (afterwards I thought of lg.learning as learning-theory).  At this point it looks like lg.learning isn't restricted to COLT/ALT stuff, so what's there to distinguish it from machine-learning?  Maybe at this rate would should just make all the learning tags synonyms?

Comment: you're the expert :) - make a proposal

Comment: before I do that, do you know if it's possible to undo making two tags synonyms?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It does seem like I can delete an association though.

Answer (score -3):

Although I am far from being an expert in this, I believe that [lg.learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lg.learning)  and [machine-learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) refer to the same thing. I do not know of any other kind of learning related to TCS other than machine learning. However, [online-learning](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-learning) is a subtype of machine learning and I believe that it should be a different tag.